# Website multiple pages | template | search

Tags: php, html, templates, search

So I want to build a website i know the basics HTML and PHP, but i want:

- Have Multiple pages with a template
- Crate a new page just by inserting the content in a file/folder (title, info, text, image)
- Have search by parameter/tags, and not by text (EX: ParameterA - 1/2/3/4)
- (and eventually make an login)

What i want to know:

- Whats the name of this type of website building;
- If there is any pre-made platform/api for this;
- What languages/structures i can use;

Hope someone understands what I'm asking...
And that this is not duplicate (i could not find anything)

Comment: you could have a base.php  where you create other files with fopen and write what you want(title, info, etc) and a include to the template.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use wordpress for simple wibsite.
you can make pages & active your search box.

Download wordpress from below link :
```

http://wordpress.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CMS like TYPO3 or WordPress, it's the best way I think.